# Thumbturn And Plate Removal (Schlage)

Tags: doors, removal, knobs

[image: front]I'm unfortunately having a lot of trouble removing my thumbturn of my door.  Please see pic.  It's a Schlage that was on this house when we bought it as the model home in 2007ish.

I've tried pushing in the small hole with a small allen wrench while trying to pull the thumbturn out but that hasn't done anything.  There are no visible screws.  Thanks[image][image]

Comment: So you've tried different small hex wrenches in that hole and there's not a set screw in there that will turn?  Why are you trying to remove it?  if you're replacing it, could you try to drill out that hole?

Comment: Could we get a photo of the other side? That may have a solid connection not designed to be removed without the flange that is retained from screws on the other side.

Comment: I've never heard of someone removing the thumb turn from a deadbolt.  It is hard to tell but I wouldn't be surprised if that wasn't a screw but a permanent connection done at the factory.

Comment: I want to remove the thumb turn because I also want to remove the plate underneath.  The purpose is to install an August Smart Lock to automate my deadbolt locking.  I'll attach a picture of the other side... Thank you all for your help so far

Comment: Is there a matching small hole opposite the one you've shown us?  If so you'll need to punch the pin out to release the thumb knob.  It will require more force that you're likely able to deliver with a small allen wrench--you might manage with a nail and a hammer.

Comment: Nope, there is no matching small hole unfortunately...thanks a lot for your help though John

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar lock. Press straight down in the center of the hole with an awl while wiggling the knob and pulling gently.  There is a small spring loaded pin that has to be depressed to remove the knob

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.